# Account.SalesforceCustomer Could not resolve standard field's name. -Error

Tags: deployment

I got this error while doing a migration:

> Account.SalesforceCustomer    Custom Field -Could not resolve standard field's name.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Are you referring to Accounts that are using CustomerPortal?

Comment: Thanks Shailesh, How can i check that. I have not enabling that anywhere